# Can't fetch JSON by JavaScript in Android application

Tags: javascript, android, json

I want to fetch a json from a url and display it.
I have made a static website using only html, css and js files and it works fine.

Then I have put all the files of the website in the assets folder of my Android app and, using the web view, I tried to run the application.

Everything works fine but the json does not load in the mobile phone when I run the app.

Comment: You need to make a call to your server for your json. How have you tried communicating with the URL?

Comment: My gut says attempting to use AJAX to a server from locally served HTML in a web view is a CORS violation.

Comment: This is the code i am using 
    `var getJSON = function(url) {return new 
Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('get', url, true);
     xhr.responseType = 'json';
     xhr.onload = function() {
     var status = xhr.status;
     if (status == 200) {
      resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
     reject(status);
      }
     };
      xhr.send();
        });
      };`

Comment: **This Function works fine in the website but does not works in the android application.**